# object destructuring: how to use intermediate nested property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
var { iWantThis: { andThis, andThisToo } } = x;
```

Is there a way to get access to all three in one destructuring call? I want to avoid two calls like so:

```
var { iWantThis } = x;
var { andThis, andThisToo } = iWantThis;
```

Comment: So you're ideally trying to end up with 3 new vars: `iWantThis`, `andThis`, and `andThisToo`? Or just the second 2?

Comment: @locks answer is the most compact I can think of.

Comment: See [Unexpected destructuring behavior, having to declare a key twice when destructuring deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38667095/1048572) for an explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest I can come up with is:

```
var { iWantThis, iWantThis: { andThis, andThisToo } } = x;
```

Though I'd use `let` instead, if I'm using ES6 ;)