# Unexpected destructuring behavior, having to declare a key twice when destructuring deeper

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was doing some destructuring in ES6 and ran into an unexpected situation.  Here's a trivialized version of what happened.

```
let obj = {x: {y: 5}};
let {x: {y}} = obj;

console.log(x); // x is not defined
console.log(y); // 5
```

In my use case, I needed access to both `x` and `y`.  I would have expected `x` to have been destructured as well.  Instead, to get the desired effect, I had to do this:

```
let obj = {x: {y: 5}};
let {x, x: {y}} = obj;

console.log(x); // {"y":5}
console.log(y); // 5
```

However, I think `{x, x: {y}}` looks weird and unintuitive.  Is there a destructuring secret I'm not aware of, or is this just a tiny destructuring pitfall?

Comment: As for intuitiveness of  your expectations, how would you expect `const {x: {x}} = {x: {x: 5}}` to behave? Should it destructure the first `x` and then reassign `x` to the second `x`? But `x` is a constant and can't be reassigned. Should it throw `x has already been declared` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a pitfall but the expected behaviour, something that is defined by [destructuring syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

There may be `AssignmentPropertyList` in `ObjectAssignmentPattern` and nested `AssignmentPropertyList` in `AssignmentPropertyList`. Each `AssignmentPropertyList` can be either `AssignmentProperty` or  `PropertyName : AssignmentElement`.

In this case

```
let {x, x: {y}} = obj;
```

the first `x` is `AssignmentProperty`, the second `x` is `PropertyName`.

The idea behind nested destructuring is to provide a path for nested property that will be destructured. The expected behaviour is to *not* get unwanted variables for each level of nested destructuring, intermediate `x` should be destructured explicitly if necessary.

There should be nothing weird or nonintuitive in this syntax for the developer who is familiar with it. The variation that is  closer to what the code does (and possibly more readable) is

```
let {x} = obj;
let {y} = x;
```

Comment: Thanks for insulting me along the way! 

Comment: @BlueJ774 I didn't have an insult in mind. But glad I could help any way.

Comment: "There should be nothing weird or nonintuitive in this syntax for the developer who is familiar with it."  I'm just saying, this surprised me and a second developer.  We've both been writing enterprise ES6 code for two years.

Comment: @BlueJ774 Best to think of destructuring kind of like the opposite of creating an object, where `let y = 5; let obj = {x: {y}};` doesn't try to read an `x` to get the key, destructuring doesn't try to write to an `x` variable.

Comment: There's no humiliation in this sentence, it is about degree of familiarity. I wasn't very fond of how unreadable the code becomes with some ES6+ features a year ago, now I'm totally ok with how they look there. As for destructuring, I'm not confused with `let {x, x: {y}}` but still prefer `let {x} = obj; let {y} = x`, it just looks right.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your intention with the sentence.

Comment: @BlueJ774 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
let {x: {y}} = obj;
```

is an abbreviation for:

```
let {x: {y: y}} = obj;
```

Destructuring matches the colons’ left-hand sides (the keys) against the data and puts the results into the right-hand sides (assignment targets, usually variables). Therefore, `x` is just a key here, while `y` is both a key and a newly declared variable.

Comment: Thanks, @AxelRauschmayer, nice to have an answer from you here. Sounds like simple but intelligible explanation to me.