# Why did ECMASCRIPT 6 reverse the sides for assignment when destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

Why did ES6 decide that left-side assignment made more sense or was more useful for destructured assignments?  Just on first look, it seems to make code more error prone, now that assignment can happen on both sides, depending on situation.

```
let obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' };
let { first: f, last: l } = obj;
// f = 'Jane'
// l = 'Doe'
```

f and l are both seemingly being defined on the left, using values from a combination of the var names on the left and values of those vars from the right.

Given that the rationale for this sytax is the keep it the same as object declaration syntax, why would ECMA not instead have used:

```
let { f: first, l: last } = obj;
```

Comment: "now that assignment can happen on both sides" The variables you assign to is still on the left side, the data you assign to those variables still on the right, no?

Comment: can you show some code you think is confusing to you?

Comment: you mean why in `const {foo: bar} = a` the new varable is `bar` not `foo`?

Comment: @tkausi no; I'll add an example of array destructuring.

Comment: And what's your alternative?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, something like 
let { f, l } = obj {first, last};

Comment: OK, but that's not destructuring then.

Comment: Compare obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' } with { first: f, last: l } = obj.  Even there, the order is reversed.

Comment: @BrianFreud I don't know how you expect your alternative to work - objects are _not_ ordered so doing `let {f, l} = obj` is going to give you RANDOM properties from the object. So, if you want to have specific properties, you'd need to lable them...which leaves you with `let {first: f, last: l}`. The thing you find "confusing" and "error prone" yet it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: @BrianFreud `Compare obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' } with { first: f, last: l } = obj. Even there, the order is reversed.` sure, because they have a very different meaning, however, both of them assign the right side to the left side.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "reversed". Assignment goes from right (source value) to left (target).

Comment: @melpomene see Kos' comment above.  In the destructured syntax, assignment goes from left (value) to right (target var)

Comment: No, `first` is not a value. It's part of the structure of the object we're in. It plays the same role as `{`, `,` or `}`.

Comment: @vlaz, forget that I used {}; I intended something like a tuple's collection, not literal object notation.  Something like let ( f, l ) = obj (first, last) if you like, where first and last are getting their values from obj.

Comment: JavaScript objects are like records. Records are tuples where the values are identified by name, not position (`first: ..., last: ...`). This seems all consistent to me. Your syntax (object slicing) wouldn't work for function parameters, where you only specify the "left" side.

Comment: @BrianFreud are you confused at what left and right are? Because `let {first: f, last: l} = obj` _is_ left assignment. Left - left side of the equals, right - right side of the equals. The assignment is clearly on the left side. The fact that `f` is "on the right" of the identifier `first` does not make it "right assignment".

Comment: Destructuring syntax designates *a path* to nested properties. See [this answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38667613/3731501). If you have problems with interpreting this syntax, take some time to become comfortable with it. It's like complaining that spread and rest operators behave differently. They are different things - so object literals and destructuring are.

Comment: @vlaz, let {first: f, last: l} = obj contains three assignments.  melpomene, you can define both a left and right (default value) for function params.  Sticking with the existing syntax, though, why would you not want { f: first, l: last } as the order?  Estus, that doesn't really have much to do, imho, with the chosen order of "first: f" over "f: first", especially when the rationale for the syntax is "to make it the same syntax as object declaration"...  when in reality, it looks the same but reverses the order.

Comment: `et {first: f, last: l} = obj contains three assignments` no, it doesn't. It's clearly _two_ - the `f` and the `l`.

Comment: I completely agree with @BrianFreud's original question. `let { f: first, l: last } = obj;` makes so much more sense cognitively. The first thing you recognize is a familiar pattern of object property assignment `{f: first}` which in your mind has the key "f" get the value (contained by) "first". When you scan the (ES6 correct) code `let {first:f, last:l} = obj` your mind sees the "first" and "last" as keys. You are much more likely to (mistakenly) assume that "first" is the var name, not "f".

I, like the OP, would love to better understand the REASON it was decided to be that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is supposed to keep the object literal syntax: the property name comes before the colon. The syntax is supposed to nest, and that wouldn't work properly if the target was on the left side:

```
let {propName: [arrayElement, ...moreElements], otherName: {nestedProp: targetName}} = obj;
```

In your approach, it would be

```
let {[arrayElement, ...moreElements]: propName, {targetName = nestedProp}: otherName} = obj;
```

where the colon doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Good point, but one could argue that the colon doesn't make any sense regardless and including it in the destructuring synrax is the source of the confusion to begin with...

Comment: Right - they could have done away with that colon in favour of some other token. This is just very confusing - it looks like you're assigning to a property `first` the value (contained by) `obj.f`, which is in fact the opposite of what's occuring. `{first -> f, last -> l} = obj` might have been a better approach

Comment: @TomAuger The operator really doesn't matter. `:` in JavaScript is what `->` is in PHP or Scala.

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't making a syntactic point, but a cognitive one. When you're designing a new language construct, with a new kind of operator, you have the opportunity to decide what token expresses the function of the operator. The decision to use ":" to alias `oldkey : newkey` does not exactly correspond to the existing paradigm of `key : value`.

Comment: @TomAuger It's not `oldkey : newkey` but rather `key: target`, which matches `key: value` just fine.