# Is destructuring Structs faster than multi-line variable assignment in Rust?

Tags: rust, destructuring

I have come across destructuring Structs or Enums during pattern matching. After sometime, It got used to it, and it became one of my favorite features in Rust. However, destructuring a struct's field into separate variables are very hard to read for newcomers. Take this code as an example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}
    
fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 10.3, y: 0.4 };
    let Point { x: top_edge, y: left_edge } = point;
    
    println!("{:?}", point);
    println!("x: {}, y: {}", top_edge, left_edge);
}
```

The assignments take the **right value** and put the value into the **left variable** in most programming languages. But in the destructuring case, we introduce `let` a structure `Point` with fields `{ x: top_edge, y: left_edge }` and assign the `point` structure variable to it. Interpreting this line of code is challenging.

Unlike Python, there is no multi-variable assignment in Rust. For example, this code will not compile.

```rust
let top_edge, left_edge = point.x, point.y;
let top_edge, left_edge = point; // Or even this
```

Instead, the fields of the struct can be assigned using multiple line of code.

```rust
let point = Point { x: 10.3, y: 0.4 };
let top_edge = point.x;
let left_edge = point.y;
    
println!("{:?}", point);
println!("x: {}, y: {}", top_edge, left_edge);
```

Personally, I think it is more readable and if we count the number of characters, then the lengths of the destructuring and the multi-line assignment are *almost* the same.

Is there any performance benefit using destructuring over multi-line variable assignment?

Comment: Doubtful that there would ever be an observable performance difference. However, "this Rust code is not useful to people who don't know Rust" is not a compelling reason to avoid a good feature. Parallel assignment would also confuse people who don't know Python (in C++, `a, b = 1, 2` is two applications of the comma operator and simply assigns `b = 1` in the middle, for instance), so should we also avoid that?

Comment: _"Unlike Python, there is no multi-variable assignment in Rust."_ That's not entirely true. You can assign and destructure a tuple in one step, which is pretty much the exact same thing: `let (top_edge, left_edge) = (point.x, point.y);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The assignments take the *right value* and put the value into the *left variable* in most programming languages

Assignments, yes. Destructuring patterns, no. Having the pattern alias on the left and the pattern target to its right is the behaviour in any programming language that features destructuring patterns<sup>1</sup>, and makes sense since it allows natural nesting. See e.g. [Why did ECMASCRIPT 6 reverse the sides for assignment when destructuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40698433/1048572) for the same confusion in JavaScript.

> there is no multi-variable assignment in Rust

Actually there is, it just requires parenthesis for the tuple.

```
let (top_edge, left_edge) = (point.x, point.y);
```

[Since Rust 1.59.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/02/24/Rust-1.59.0.html#destructuring-assignments) it also works without the `let` declaration.

> I think it is more readable and if we count the number of characters, then the lengths of the destructuring and the multi-line assignment are almost the same.

Yes, but that's not specific to Rust either, it's the same in any programming language with destructuring patterns when renaming the fields. However, it's much more common to assign the fields to variables of the same name, i.e.

```
let Point { x, y } = point;
println!("x: {}, y: {}", x, y);
```

This is where destructuring shines.

> Is there any performance benefit using destructuring over multi-line variable assignment?

I really doubt there is, I'd hope that both compile to the exact same machine code.

<sub>1: …that I've encountered so far</sub>

Comment: Making multiple bindings with `let` has been in rust probably since tuples were added. The only thing introduced in 1.59 is assigning to multiple already declared variables, which doesn't use `let`.

Comment: @drewtato Yes, that's why I wrote "also". I presumed that by "*multi-variable assignment*" the OP referred to the statement without `let`, just like in Python (although in Python you cannot distinguish between declaration and assignment). I assume that a `let` declaration in Rust is not considered to be an "assignment" syntactically? I'm no expert on the Rust grammar.